# How to create events on outlook using microsoft graph api after login with sso

Tags: angular, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-calendar, msal-angular

I have a app that fetches the token after sso login with Microsoft. I want to create event for using that token. But it gives an error when I use that token to create an event. The token that is generate by the graph explorer works fine but the token generated from sso login doesn't work.

I am using angular. the package for sso is @azure/msal-angular

```
 this.authService.loginPopup({redirectUri: 'http://localhost:4200',scopes: [ 'openid' ,'profile' ,'email' ,'Calendars.ReadWrite', 'Calendars.Read' ,'User.Read']})
    .subscribe({
      next: (result) => {
        console.log(result.accessToken); // using this access token 
       }
}
)
        




 url - https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendar/events
 
 body- {
    "subject": "Let's go for lunch",
    "body": {
        "contentType": "HTML",
        "content": "Does noon work for you?"
    },
    "start": {
        "dateTime": "2022-01-15T12:00:00",
        "timeZone": "India Standard Time"
    },
    "end": {
        "dateTime": "202-01-15T14:00:00",
        "timeZone": "India Standard Time"
    },
    "location": {
        "displayName": "Harry's Bar"
    },
    "attendees": [
        {
            "emailAddress": {
                "address": "ankitgupyta8768@gmail.com",
                "name": "Ankit Gupta"
            },
            "type": "required"
        }
    ],
    "allowNewTimeProposals": true,
    "transactionId": "7E163156-7762-4BEB-A8C6-729EA81755A8"
}


response- 
{"error":{"code":"NoPermissionsInAccessToken","message":"The token contains no permissions, or permissions can not be
understood.","innerError":{"oAuthEventOperationId":"7e74af78-358d-4f90-9b8d-b2656365592b","oAuthEventcV":"FyQYtJaGIm6+7397Aa/oLw.1.1","errorUrl":"https://aka.ms/autherrors#error-InvalidGrant","requestId":"3fb81b0a-42a8-47a0-995b-06d1301a3e0a","date":"2022-01-21T08:02:04"}}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should configure the [MsalInterceptor](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-angular/docs/v2-docs/msal-interceptor.md)

It will automatically add a token to all requests for a specific protected resource `https://graph.Microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendar/events/*` in this case.

It will even requests extra consent if that is needed for the current request.

The [docs](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-angular/docs/v2-docs/initialization.md) are generally pretty complete. If you follow along you should end up with an angular application that does most of the token stuff for you. No need to worry about tokens.